# How to modify a non-const argument to a const one while using a Qt5 constructor?

Tags: c++, qt5

Is there a workaround to use the following constructor

```
QDataStream::QDataStream(QByteArray *a, QIODevice::OpenMode mode)
```

with `const QByteArray`? like its predecessor:

```
QDataStream::QDataStream(const QByteArray &a)
```

in the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatastream.html#QDataStream-2).

EDIT:

Here's my code:

```
KeySequence KeyboardShortcutsDialog::keySequenceFromByteArray(QByteArray& seq)
{
    KeySequence sequence;
    QDataStream stream(&seq, QIODevice::ReadOnly);
    stream >> sequence;
    return sequence;
}
```

Comment: With or without deep copying ?

Comment: @VictorGubin I pass it by reference to avoid copying the parameter.

Comment: The documentation is pretty clear about the usage of both constructors. If you want to read from the array, use the first constructor. If you want to write to the array, use the second one. If you want to write, you can't pass a const reference.

Comment: Please, find my function below. It's a read-only use.

```KeySequence KeyboardShortcutsDialog::keySequenceFromByteArray(QByteArray& seq)
{

    KeySequence sequence;

    QDataStream stream(&seq, QIODevice::ReadOnly);

    stream >> sequence;

    return sequence;

}```

Comment: Please put the code in the question.  Having said that, why can't you simply use ` QDataStream stream(seq)` instead of `QDataStream stream(&seq, QIODevice::ReadOnly)`?  You can pass a non-const `QByteArray` by reference to a function that expects a `const QByteArray &`.

Comment: @MohammedDeifallah What's wrong with your code? Your code should compile fine.

Comment: @frogatto It compiles fine. The problem is that I need the function parameter to be const. So this would result in a compilation error.

Comment: @MohammedDeifallah If you need a read-only data stream from the byte array, use this constructor: `QDataStream::QDataStream(const QByteArray &a)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the comments to my question. I found out that the correct solution is to use the constructor `QDataStream::QDataStream(const QByteArray &a)` for read-only uses.